# GGMap comes up as blue

Tags: r, ggmap

```
NBN_lat <- c(53.37074)
NBN_lon <- c(-1.40705)

NBN_mapcoord <- c(left = ((NBN_lat)-0.1), bottom = ((NBN_lon)-0.1), right =((NBN_lat+0.1)), top = (
(NBN_lon)+0.1))

NBN_map <- get_stamenmap(NBN_mapcoord, zoom = 5)
NBN_map

ggmap(NBN_map)
```

Is my code, when I run the script [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1msgF.png) map is produced.

A similar code to plot everest meanwhile works. The NBN_lat and NBN_lon have the relevant data values in the data frame so I'd expect it to plot normally (my code is slightly different than what I posted, as it links to .csv to pull the lon/lat coordinates. The +0.1 and -0.1 I added thinking it'd help with map data to be produced as it'd give me two different values for left/bottom and right/top.

```
library(ggmap)
library(mapproj)

bbox_everest <- c(left = 86.05, bottom = 27.21, right = 87.81, top = 28.76) #makes use of mapproj
map6 <- get_stamenmap(bbox_everest, zoom = 6)
ggmap(map6)
```

I know stamenmaps doesn't have full mapping data, but when I searched for Sheffield (the location of the coords) it appeared on stamenmaps.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your plot is blue because you're not trying to plot Sheffield, you're trying to plot the Indian Ocean. You have inverted the values of longitude and latitude when writing `NBN_mapcoord`.

If you switch longitude and latitude around and increase the resolution, you get this:

```r
NBN_lon <- c(-1.40705)
NBN_lat <- c(53.37074)

NBN_mapcoord <- c(left  = ((NBN_lon) - 0.1), bottom = ((NBN_lat) - 0.1), 
                  right = ((NBN_lon + 0.1)), top    = ((NBN_lat) + 0.1))

NBN_map <- get_stamenmap(NBN_mapcoord, zoom = 12)

ggmap(NBN_map)
```

[image]

Comment: One last thing - if the 'zoom' is resolution, does this mean zoom = 12 and zoom = 5 would cover the same map area, yet zoom = 12 will be more precise to the inclusion of roads etc.